# ASP.Net MVC3 user authentication tutorials

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, razor

I'm currently working as a developer on a website, and it's more or less my first time doing any sort of web development. We're currently at a stage that we need to do user authentication, but I have absolutely no idea how I can accomplish this.

To that end I've tried to do some googling and searching on SO, but my google-fu is currently failing me.

**Are there any tutorials that can take me from knowing nothing about authentication, to being to set up some secure authentication on my website?**

We're developing this under MVC3 with Razor view engine, if it helps at all.

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own authentication or do you want to use the Microsoft one that is built in?

Comment: @JamieRRytlewski I would like to use what's the most secure. I'll implement my own if I can find out how to do it in the first place, but if the Microsoft one is the better choice I'll do that.

Comment: Mike, in the .Net world, the "Microsoft one" is usually better!

Comment: If your new to web development and authentication, DO NOT try and roll your own. Start with an existing, well-tested and comprehensive package like the built in membership provider. Then when you learn the good and bad things (mostly the bad things), you will know what can be improved and only then should you attempt to roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) is a good starting point. The fact that it's **MVC3** isn't really going to change anything (i.e., the Razor view engine doesn't change anything about authentication in MVC)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ASP.NET MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) example application, specifically [Part 7](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-7).

Answer (score 1):

what ErOx posted + [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75%28VS.80%29.aspx) is sample implementation of custom MembershipProvider